# How should I divide Party Monster XP witha 2nd lvl fighter and a 6th lvl fighter in the party

Tags: dnd-3.5e, experience-points

I had 2 new players join my group. They are now 2nd lvl. My highest lvl player is a 6th lvl fighter. I have a large party of 10, 7 PCs, 3 NPCs. The XP for a CR 3 is 600 for a 6th lvl character and 900XP for a 2nd lvl character.
How should I calculate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy. As detailed on page 37 of the Dungeon Master's Guide, **divide the rewards by the number of characters in your group.**

- Your 6th level character gets 600/10 = 60 XP
- Your 2nd level characters gain 900/10 = 90 XP each.
- Your NPCs gain half what they would have gained if they were PCs, effectively eating up some of the encounter experience.

If those NPCs are Leadership cohorts, familiars, animal companions, special mounts or the like, they're considered part of their "owner". Don't count them as characters when divinding experience.
Yes, this makes Leadership a very strong feat.

---

Please note that the manual asks you to calculate your XP prizes for every single monster in the encounter, rather than on the total CR.
If an encounter has a very high level monster and several low level minions, it's possible the higher level character won't get XP at all from the minions and the low level characters would get a lot of XP from the boss, making it easier to catch up.

---

[This page does the math for you.](http://www.d20srd.org/extras/d20encountercalculator/)